# NNDSVD to initialize Convex-NMF

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

I'm working with the Convex Nonnegative Matrix Factorization Algorithm described in [Ding, Li, Jordan 2008 ("Convex and Semi-Nonnegative Matrix
Factorizations")](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=4685898&tag=1).

Good initialization strategies make all the difference and using the described k-means clustering to get started works very well.

But there is a paper describing [NNDSVD (Boutsidis, Gallopoulos, 2007)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320307004359) to initialize "traditional" NMF Algos. I wanted to test this, to see if it improves my results.

The nonnegativity constraints for Convex-NMF are relaxed. X can have mixed sign data, where X ~ XWG', with factors W and G having only positive data.
I've implemented NNDSVD just like in the paper (in C++ w/ OpenCV), but since X has mixed sign data, the resulting W contains negative values as well.

Has anyone tried to adapt this initialization strategy? Are there any other recommended initialization strategies for Convex-NMF, aside from the ones mentioned in the Ding et al Paper (and random init)?

Comment: can you add links to the papers (or at least the abstracts)?

Comment: Sure! I've added them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've played before with a library for ("classic") NMF from University of Vienna: [libNMF](http://www.univie.ac.at/rlcta/software/)

While it wasn't useful for me at first, since they don't implement Convex-NMF, I had a look at their NNDSVD implementation.
They simply **replace all negative values** and values smaller than the machine epsilon **with zero**.

I tried that, but it fails, since the update rules for Convex-NMF are such that I get a division by zero. Since they **add 0.2 to all values** in their proposed initialization scheme (for "smoothing"), I just did the same here.

It works, the precision is worse than expected (a bit worse than k-means, which is my best approach for now), but I'll tweak it a bit more.